# Uncaught TypeError: ol.control.Timeline is not a constructor

Tags: openlayers, node-js

I have been trying to create a timeline in my openlayers map. However it shows that it is not a constructor. How to fix this? this is my code

```
var tline = new ol.control.Timeline({
  className: 'ol-pointer',
  graduation: 'day', 
  minDate:new Date('2020/05/1'),
     maxDate:new Date('2020/06/1')
});
map.addControl(tline);

tline.addButton({
  className:'go',
  Title:'GO!',
  handleClick: function(){
    go();
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a Timeline control in openlayers? I can't find anything when I search. Only an extension here: https://github.com/volpino/openlayers-timeline. Try to run `typeof ol.control.Timeline` in the console and see what you get. If `typeof ol.control.Timeline` returns `undefined` your code will give the errormessage ol.control.Timeline is not a constructor

Comment: The link above is for an OpenLayers 2 extension which uses the syntax `OpenLayers.Timeline`. For version 3 and later your example appears to refer to the ol-ext library https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/storymap/map.control.timeline.html